# Building CDT projects from commandline

Tags: eclipse, terminal, centos, eclipse-cdt, root

I'm having trouble running a CDT build from the command line when super user.  I can run the following command as a regular user, but when I am super user eclipse tells me an error has occured and crashes.

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild
```

I am well aware that this command is missing parameters, but even running this as a regular user won't crash eclipse, it simply complains about missing parameters.  My question is, why is it having a problem running as super user.

The log file it generates is not much help and just tells me

`!MESSAGE Application error`

This is on a CentOS 5 machine.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're being a little sparse with details. What does "crashed" mean? Exactly what happens? Are you getting a dialog? If so, what does it say?

A wild guess is that Eclipse needs a display, and the DISPLAY variable is not set. I suspect that even the headless CDT builder needs a display.